# Strawberry Perl SCP

Tags: perl, scp, strawberry-perl

I'm trying to follow the example shown in [`Net::SCP`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SCP)

I'm using strawberry perl with eclipse in my windows dev machine. Eventually the script will be run on a linux server to distribute some config files as part of a deploy process.

Eclipse complains that `use Net::SCP qw(scp iscp);` can't be located:

`Can't locate Net/SCP.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Net::SCP module) (@INC
 contains: C:/strawberry/perl/site/lib C:/strawberry/perl/vendor/lib C:/strawberry/perl/lib
 .)`

Since I'm new to perl, my question is a multi-parter. Is the above example a good one to follow? If so, how do I install the missing module. If it is not, what alternative should I use?

Comment: Did you install Net::SCP? `cpan Net::SCP`

Comment: Thanks ikegami, that looks to be what I was missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is the above example a good one to follow?

[`Net::SCP`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SCP) is just a simple wrappers around ssh and scp commands.

Given you're developing on Strawberry Perl on Windows, you probably won't have access to these system commands and therefore won't be able to use the module.

The [#See Also](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SCP#SEE-ALSO) section states: *For a perl implementation that does not require the system scp command, see [`Net::SFTP`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SFTP) instead.*

> If so, how do I install the missing module.

To install modules use `cpan` or `cpanm` as documented at http://www.cpan.org/modules/INSTALL.html